# WebRTC multiple video streams in same peerConnection

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, sdp

I am working on a WebRTC client and I would like to allow the clients to modify the ongoing audio/video session to add or remove an audio or video stream.

So for instance if there is an ongoing audio/video call between two clients, one client can modify the session and add another video stream to share his screen. So the remote client can see the video from the camera, and the video captured from the screen.

I do the modification by sending a re-INVITE with the updated SDP that will supposedly contain two video media lines.

My question is, would it be possible for the receiver to receive such SDP and deal with each video media line independently but over the same peerConnection?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible

Answer (score 9):

- firefox is limited to 1 audio and 1 video now.
- handling of multiple streams in a PC is still subject to 3 approaches: plan A, plan B and unified plan [[here]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-roach-mmusic-unified-plan-00). Hangout uses plan B, which is obviously supported by chrome for the time being. Firefox has announced they will support unified plan, ... the day they implement the feature.
- in short, as the sdp interpretation is done by the browser, it is NOT possible today.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been reading Plan B and the example that is shown there is exactly what I wanted to implement. I suppose it will work on Chrome.
Is there anything I do not understand that you say it is NOT possible today? Apart from Firefox.

Comment: it is possible in chrome and that's it. The jitsi team, which is using plan B as well in their meet me bridge, has interconnection with hangout, but it comes at the price of not working in firefox. They have an one bug against firefox that has been ignored for quite some time. google jitsi+plan B+firefox.

Comment: I'm very confused, which plan A and plan B were you referring to?

Comment: plan B: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-uberti-rtcweb-plan-00
Unified Plan: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-roach-mmusic-unified-plan-00

Comment: @Dr. Alex Gouaillard the link you provided is a research paper or something. Is there a working solution with code example?